# Store username and password for API in cookie?

Tags: security, http, cookies, https

I've written a web application that interfaces to an API, in a different domain.

This API requests a username and password for certain calls (involving POST, e.g. to upload a photo to the API). For these calls the API uses https.

Is there a way I can store the username and password within the web app, so the user doesn't have to log in repeatedly each time they upload a photo?

Here's what I can think of:

1. The obvious way is to stick both in a cookie, but clearly that's a security hole, whether plaintext or hashed.
2. If it were a secure website, I could use a session ID: could I persuade the API owners to allow session IDs, or would that be impossible across domains?

Perhaps I simply have to ask the user to re-enter their username and password each time they make an API call.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your architecture correctly, your users are sending the API calls to a service running in a different domain. You are not a man-in-the-middle for this request, you are only providing the interface e.g. as a form-field in your web application. The user can send the API calls without you even knowing that he did.

In that case there is no way to implement this without storing some kind of authentication information in the browser (cookie, form-field, etc.) or have your users enter them for each request. They must come from somewhere and your server is not involved in the request.

What you can do is changing the architecture and start playing man-in-the-middle, like a proxy. Instead of just providing the interface, let the users send their requests to your web application instead of communicating with the service directly. Your web application adds the credentials and forwards the request to the service. The answer of the service will be sent to your web application, which can redirect it again to the user.

In this scenario your web application is responsible for authentication. Your web application adds the credentials to a request if the user sending the request was identified and has the required permissions. The credentials for the service are only passed from your web application to the service, they even can be kept hidden from the user himself.

Such a change has several implications of course. The load on your web application will increase and the logic will become more complex. Those trade offs must be considered.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, your interpretation of the architecture is correct. You mean I could ask for a username and password the first time, then store that securely *server-side* in my application, and use sessions or similar to keep people logged in to my application?